# Can't log in to my LinkedIn account

Tags: linkedin, account-recovery, login

I've attempted to login to my LinkedIn account but I was told I will get a verification code to log in. However, the code wasn't sent to me. My email address is old and not in use. How can I get access to the LinkedIn account to close it?